# Realm query emit items on each write operation

Tags: android, realm

Realm query emit items on each write operation. Even if the same data as stored in realm was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if the same data as stored in realm was written.

Realm knows that you made a write operation to a given object, and that a given property was set to a given value.

[It doesn't do an equality check and say "oh it's the same thing so I'm not going to write it" because that wouldn't work in Sync scenario.](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2787)

And it also can't know that you "didn't mean to do a write", similarly to how if you write `null` or `0` as a value, it can't know you "didn't intend to set this value".

So the solution is that if you want to *control* your writes, then you should do it by hand: don't call the setter if the value is equal to that of the managed object's.